# How can I use a variable name instead of addresses when debugging valgrind runs with gdb?

Tags: gdb, valgrind

Let's say I'm debugging with `valgrind` and `gdb` by doing:

```
$ valgrind --vgdb-error=0 ./magic
```

...and then in a second terminal:

```
$ gdb ./magic
...
(gdb) target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb
```

If I want to examine the defined-ness of some memory, I can use:

```
(gdb) p &batman
$1 = (float *) 0xffeffe20c
(gdb) p sizeof(batman)
$2 = 4
(gdb) monitor get_vbits 0xffeffe20c 4
ffffffff
```

Using three commands to do one thing is kind of annoying, especially since I usually want to do this a few times for many different variables in the same stack frame. But if I try the obvious thing, I get:

```
(gdb) monitor get_vbits &batman sizeof(batman)
missing or malformed address
```

Is it possible to get `gdb` to evaluate `&batman` and `sizeof(batman)` *on the same line* as my `monitor` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But if I try the obvious thing, I get: missing or malformed address

This is from GDB doc (http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Connecting.html#index-monitor-1210) for the monitor cmd:

> `monitor cmd`
>
> This command allows you to send arbitrary commands
>   directly to the remote monitor. Since gdb doesn't care about the
>   commands it sends like this, this command is the way to extend gdb—you
>   can add new commands that only the external monitor will understand
>   and implement.

As you can see "gdb doesn't care about the commands it sends like this". It probably means that the command after `monitor` is not processed in any way and sent AS IS.

What you can do to evaluate your variable on the same line is to use user defined commands in gdb (http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html). Define your own comand and use the `eval` gdb command to prepare your command with necessary values  (http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html#index-eval-1744):

```
define monitor_var
  eval "monitor get_vbits %p %d", &$arg0, sizeof($arg0)
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
(gdb) monitor_var batman
```